# How can I change velocity by a certain factor for a certain time, while remaining consistent at different framerates?

Tags: algorithm, game-physics, velocity, frame-rate

This is for a game, and I want the velocity of a certain object to decrease at a rate of 98% per frame, when the framerate is 30 frames per second. But, the framerate can be anything between 30 and 60 frames per second. The best solution I came up with was the following:

velocity *= 1.0 - 0.02 * (delta / maxDelta);

So in this case, if the framerate is 30 fps, the velocity will be multiplied by 1.0 - 0.02 * 1.0 = 0.98. If the framerate were 60 fps, the velocity would be multiplied by 1.0 - 0.02 * 0.5 = 0.99. But this is not exactly correct, since at 60 fps, after 2 frames the factor will be 0.9801, not 0.98. Almost there, but not exactly. Is there a simple way to do this more precisely? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagining for a moment that your FPS will always be 30, can we express the velocity as a straightforward analytic function of the frame number, rather than as an incremental algorithm?
Yes we can, `v = 0.98 ^ frame_number`. The `^` is exponentiation.

Then we can reformulate that as a function of time (in seconds): `v = 0.98 ^ (total_time_elapsed * 30)`. But then we notice this function is continuous and doesn't depend on the frame length.

If you really need to make it an incremental formula, it can be worked back into `v = v * 0.98 ^ (time_elapsed_since_previous_frame * 30)`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I suppose you want to achieve [**determinism**](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Determinism). You want the output to be independent of the frame rate.

Most physics engines perform uniform time stepping to be deterministic. You can read about uniform time stepping [**here**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step), and a [**tutorial**](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-core-engine--gamedev-7493#timestepping) to implement the same.

---

**Benefits:**

- After implementing uniform time-stepping, you can simply implement constant acceleration which would look realistic without using complex hacky velocity formula.
- While this may look as some additional work, this is the time-tested approach used by most physics engines. So many resources that you find would be more relevant too.
- Implementing this would give you freedom to toy with more complex velocity logic without worrying about frame rate.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I understand determinism, but I really need the game to run between 30 and 60 fps.

60 fps is the ideal, but some mobile phones won't handle 60 fps, and when that happens with deterministic physics the whole game slows down.

This also happens in Flash games, the fps will sometimes be 30 for no apparent reason, even though the computer can do 60.

Comment: The tutorial link I gave you shows how to implement deterministic physics which runs exactly same for all frame rates. It won't *slow down*. You just need to scale it linearly with time.

Comment: Oh, it seems I misunderstood then. I am using the HaxeFlixel framework, which has fixed or variable timesteps, and when I use fixed the game does slow down. I can't really use a proper physics engine now, since I had very specific needs and did my own solution. But I'll take a look at the tutorial, it seems interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Good luck.